# Django, following a tutorial and there's an issue where my {% block content %} is not being recognized

Tags: python, html, django

Here's the dir structure:
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFGE.png)

If the image isn't displaying here's a text version:

- templates

  - myapp
  - - new_search.html
  - base.html

base.html code:

```
{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}
```

new_search.html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>NEW SEARCH</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

I can display the base.html fine. 
The new_search.html however displays like this:

[new_search.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMLq9.png)

I also want to mention a side question. My Django server isn't running however I can still open the html in my browser. Is that supposed to happen? My URLs when opening both html's are:

base.html:
http://localhost:63342/Full-Stack%20Web%20App/myapp/templates/base.html?_ijt=rtiq5iv3jude6ijjmu0ept2i82

new_search.html:
http://localhost:63342/Full-Stack%20Web%20App/myapp/templates/myapp/new_search.html?_ijt=rtiq5iv3jude6ijjmu0ept2i82

Also, i'm getting this error when trying to visit my home page:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBTb.png)

EDIT:
Adding more info. I now get this error. And my new_search template still isn't including the base template. I tried moving the html to different directories etc. In the tutorial it matches too.

[template Doesn't Exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nV2I.png)

it says the source doesn't exist but I can see it right there. [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nlz6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try copying "base.html" in templates --> myapp folder.

Basically maintain both hmtl files in the same directory.

And also try giving full path after copying them in same dir, like:

`{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}`

Comment: I tried the directories thing. No joy. I also tried the full path and still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

For the home page, you need to have the tag {% load static %} to be able to use the static tag.

Make sure you are using the render() function in your view so it doesn't just return the template as text
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: Thank you for fixing my home page issue. The my function looks like this:

def new_search(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/new_search.html')